# How to link CSS file to html page on Brackets

Tags: html, css

I am having troubles linking my css file to one of my pages i created. The uploaded pictures shows my attempt in linking the two, and the code in the css file. The css file and html file are both in the same folder.However, my homepage won't recognise the css. Any help would much appreciated. Thank you.

[linking the css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fe2jD.jpg)

[css file code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8i5W.jpg)

Comment: https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/website/how-to-link-a-stylesheet-css-file-to-your-html-file

Comment: I used their format, and its still not working

Comment: where is you html file and where is your css file css file is in different location or same location..?

Comment: both the html file and css file are in the same sub folder called coursework

Comment: check below answer and apply one class in ur tag that is linking with css file for example change `font-size` or change color for some paragraph or anything for checking the css file is linked or not..

Comment: Thank you Kiran! i have managed to fix it with your guidance. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically Styles can be linking to an HTML document using one of three methods:

1. Inline Style
2. Embedded Style (Internal Style)
3. External Style

How do you connect a CSS styling sheet to an HTML page

1. **Inline Style**

   **Inline Style** is the simplest method of adding CSS styles to your HTML pages. An inline style is applied to an HTML document via its style attribute to specific tags within the document,

   For example, If you want to add styles to < p > then you can code like this:

   `<p style="color: #0000FF">...<p>`

   The above declaration will ensure that the paragraph text will be blue. This method can be applied to any HTML element within the `< body > .... < /body >` of the HTML page.

Example:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p style="color: #0000FF">
      Instyle Paragraph Testing
    </p>
    <p>
      Another Paragraph Testing
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notice that the text contained within the first `< p >` paragraph will be Blue color. You can see only that paragraph is affected, and the second paragraph defaults to black.

The major disadvantage of Inline Style is that it is impossible to reuse. Consider restructuring a website that containing hundreds of pages where inline styles litter the markup. You should have to go into every page and change each CSS property individually is a very difficult task.

2. **Embedded Style (Internal Style)**

   Embedded Styles allow you to implement any number of CSS styles by placing them between the opening and closing style tags.

   `<style>......</style>`

   You can place Style Tag within the `< head > ... < /head >` section, just after the `< title >` tag of your HTML page.

like this

```
<head>
  <style>
    ........
    ........
  </style>
</head>
```

You should start with the opening style tag like the following: `<style type="text/css">`

The opening Style tag should always use the attribute "type". The attribute value is "text/css" in the case of a CSS document.

Example :

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Embedded Style Sample</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      h1{
        color: #0000FF;
      }
      h2{
        color: #00CCFF;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Embedded Style testing</h1>
    <h2>Next Line</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

3. **External Style**

   An **external style sheet** is a plain text file that contain CSS Style formats only. The extension of the external file should end with .css extension **(e.g. pagestyle.css)**. This external file is referred to as an external style sheet.

   The external Style Sheet (.css file) always seperate from HTML file. You can link this external file (.css file) to your HTML document file using the < link > tag . You can place this < link > tag Within the `< head >` section, and after the `< title >` element of your HTML file.

   `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />`

For Example Your **HTML** File is placed inside a folder Suppose your folder name is **WebDesign** and your CSS file also placed inside that folder i.e WebDesign folder that in your html file the CSS will link like this directly

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />`